# Laravel update table from public class helper not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to update my table in my public class. But it is throwing error Method update does not exist.
This is my class

```
public static function Update($id, $city){
    $hotel_name= hotel_info::all()->where('id', $id)->pluck('hotel_name');
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $plan_hotel_db = plan_hotel::where('travel_id', $user_id)->where('plan_city_id', $city)->get();

    $plan_hotel_db->hotel_name = $hotel_name;

    $plan_hotel_db->update();

    return $plan_hotel_db;
}
```

Comment: This query can return multiple rows, do you wanna update multiple rows or only single rows?

Comment: I want to update single row

Answer (score 1):

You should get the first element of your `$plan_hotel_db`, as it will return an array of data. To fix that change your code to this.

```
public static function Update($id, $city){
    $hotel_name= hotel_info::all()->where('id', $id)->pluck('hotel_name');
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $plan_hotel_db = plan_hotel::where('travel_id', $user_id)->where('plan_city_id', $city)->first();

    $plan_hotel_db->hotel_name = $hotel_name;

    $plan_hotel_db->update();

    return $plan_hotel_db;
}
```

Or if you want to update all records of it, then you should iterate the value of `$plan_hotel_db.`

Comment: The querybuilder has a first() method so unecesary to call get() first

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method returns a collection with 0 to many rows, since you only wanna updated a single row you can utilize the query builder method first(); Therefor your query should look like this.

```
$plan_hotel_db = plan_hotel::where('travel_id', $user_id)->where('plan_city_id', $city)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first()` to get the first element.

After direct changes on the eloquent object, you can use `save()` to save the changes.

If you want to pull fresh data from db (not necessary in your case) you can use `$plan_hotel_db = $plan_hotel_db->fresh();`

```
public static function Update($id, $city){
    $hotel_name = hotel_info::all()->where('id', $id)->pluck('hotel_name');
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $plan_hotel_db = plan_hotel::where([
        ['travel_id', $user_id],
        ['plan_city_id', $city]
    ])
    ->first();

    if (!$plan_hotel_db) {
        return false;
    }

    $plan_hotel_db->hotel_name = $hotel_name;
    $plan_hotel_db->save();

    return $plan_hotel_db;
}
```